VASP simulation of 2D perovskite: Error in memory allocation
I run the VASP for 2D perovksite material. During the DoS calculation, there was an error message "operating system error: Cannot allocate memory". What is the reason behind that? How do I resolve that?

+1. Welcome to our community.

How large is your calculation (number of k-points, plane-waves, bands, spins)? Is it possible that your computer just doesn't have enough RAM?
